# Irregular/Abnormal shaped WinForms Control (Button or PictureBox)

Tags: controls, transparency

I'm searching a bit but couldn't find answer so I wanted to ask.Please don't recommend me to look "Custom Shaped WinForms Form". Question may be silly or easy, sorry for your time.

I wanted to create a button or create picture box with a certain image.
Problem is, my image has empty space inside of it and another images will be added each others around.

Example picture:
(shapes are random)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr1Rc.png

As seen in figure, wheter i click on right or left wing, same method should be called but if only i clicked on picture, not blank zone. Also in the middle of that shape another shape can be there, also that shape should be accessable only on itself.

I hope I can explain myself properly
I'm working on Winforms , C#

Note: Problem is not about visually, its about functionalty,Clicking on empty area should not trigger anything

Edit:
As a result, "Region" should solve this problem according to @Simon.

Comment: I dont have any problem with visually transparency, is that related with "functionally transparency" ? I mean if i click transperent area, nothing should happen.

Comment: When you modify a control's region (as per the answer in the question I linked), anything outside the region will not receive mouse events, so yes, this will do what you need.